# How to change WordPress post permalink structure with .html format?

Tags: wordpress, post, migration, seo, permalinks

I have an old news website in Perl, and now I have to rebuild this site in WordPress with the new design. I want to migrate all old posts into the new WP site, but one problem is created. Old site post URL structure(https://www.old-domain.com/.../86145.html) is not matched with the new one(https://www.new-domain.com/how-to-distro-hop-with-a-web-browser/). The old site has good SEO and also some posts linked with other sites. So what is the solution to this issue, please let me know.

I want the only post permalink like https://www.new-domain.com/article/86145.html

Answer (score 1):

just attach .html to the end of your custom permalink setting.

> Settings >> Permalinks >> Custom Structure

**NOTE:** Typically a custom structure has a trailing / on the end like this:

/%category%/%postname%/

You will want to remove that trailing slash, and just add .html, like this:

/%category%/%postname%.html
[image]